# RED5 - Storing streams from Flash Client

Tags: java, red5

I have a Java Application that serves Live Streaming to my Flash Client, now the streaming stuff works but how do i store the stream on the Red5 Server, im sure i last heard that you need to store the streams in your webapps folder but i dont know if i am right.

The stream variable is null?

Here is the code so far:

```
    package com;



import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.Red5;
import org.red5.server.api.scope.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.IBroadcastStream;
import org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream;

import static java.lang.System.*;


public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter{
//private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog( Application.class );

public boolean appStart(IScope scope){
    //IConnection current = Red5.getConnectionLocal();
    return true;
}

public void appStop(){
    // This function fires when the app is closing
}



public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {
        // This is the master connection method called every time someone connects
        // to the serv

    IConnection clientConnection = Red5.getConnectionLocal(); // Get the connection
     String clientIP = clientConnection.getRemoteAddress(); // Get the user's IP // // Format the current date
     //IBroadcastStream currentStream =  app.getBroadcastStream(clientConnection.getScope(), "hostStream"); // Get the current stream
     ClientBroadcastStream stream = (ClientBroadcastStream) getBroadcastStream(conn.getScope(), "tester");


     try {
        // Save the stream to disk.
        stream.saveAs("streamName", false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }   
    return true;
}
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter#disconnect(org.red5.server.api.IConnection, org.red5.server.api.IScope)
 * disconnect an user form the chat and notify all others users 
 */
public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope) {
        // Function called every time someone disconnects from the server.


    super.disconnect(conn, scope);

}   

public boolean joinuser(String username, String uid) {
    out.println("join invoked: "+username+" "+uid);
    return true;
}

public boolean removeuser(String username, String uid) {
    out.println("remove invoked: "+username+" "+uid);
    return true;
}

}
```

### MODIFIED

I get an error saying that the file cannot be saved in "streams/aaa.flv" the error says that file path cannot be resolved because the URL does not exist in the connect method.

```
package com;



import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.Red5;
import org.red5.server.api.scope.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.IBroadcastStream;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.IServerStream;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.support.SimplePlayItem;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.support.StreamUtils;
import org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream;
import org.red5.server.stream.RecordingListener;

import static java.lang.System.*;


public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter{
//private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog( Application.class );
private IServerStream serverStream;

public boolean appStart(IScope scope){
    //IConnection current = Red5.getConnectionLocal();
    return true;
}

public void appStop(){
    // This function fires when the app is closing
}

@Override
public void streamPublishStart(IBroadcastStream stream)
{
    stream.addStreamListener(new MyStreamListener());
} 

@Override
public void streamBroadcastStart(IBroadcastStream stream) {
    IConnection conn = Red5.getConnectionLocal();  
    super.streamBroadcastStart(stream);
    //log.info("streamBroadcastStart " + stream.getPublishedName() + " " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + conn.getScope().getName());

        //recordStream(stream);
        //MyStreamListener listener = new MyStreamListener(); 
        //listener.setEventRecordingService(recordingService);
        //stream.addStreamListener(listener); 
        //streamListeners.put(conn.getScope().getName() + "-" + stream.getPublishedName(), listener);

}

private void recordStream(IBroadcastStream stream) {
    IConnection conn = Red5.getConnectionLocal();   
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String recordingStreamName = stream.getPublishedName(); // + "-" + now; /** Comment out for now...forgot why I added this - ralam */

    try {           
        System.out.println("Recording stream " + recordingStreamName );
        ClientBroadcastStream cstream = (ClientBroadcastStream) this.getBroadcastStream(conn.getScope(), stream.getPublishedName());
        cstream.saveAs(recordingStreamName, false);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR while recording stream " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {
        // This is the master connection method called every time someone connects
        // to the serv

    IConnection clientConnection = Red5.getConnectionLocal(); // Get the connection
     String clientIP = clientConnection.getRemoteAddress(); // Get the user's IP // // Format the current date
     //IBroadcastStream currentStream =  app.getBroadcastStream(clientConnection.getScope(), "hostStream"); // Get the current stream
     ClientBroadcastStream stream = (ClientBroadcastStream) getBroadcastStream(conn.getScope(), "tester");
     //stream.addStreamListener(new MyStreamListener());
     serverStream = StreamUtils.createServerStream(clientConnection.getScope(), "live0");
     SimplePlayItem item = SimplePlayItem.build(clientIP);
     //item.setStart(0);
     //item.setLength(10000);
     //item.setName("avatar");
     serverStream.addItem(item);
     serverStream.start();

     try {
     serverStream.saveAs("aaa", false);
     } catch (Exception e) {} 
     try {
        // Save the stream to disk.
        // System.out.println("hello");
        //stream.saveAs("/stream1", false);         
       // System.out.println("hello2");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("sdfsdfsdf" + e.toString());
    }
    return true;
}
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter#disconnect(org.red5.server.api.IConnection, org.red5.server.api.IScope)
 * disconnect an user form the chat and notify all others users 
 */
public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope) {
        // Function called every time someone disconnects from the server.


    super.disconnect(conn, scope);

}   

public boolean joinuser(String username, String uid) {
    out.println("join invoked: "+username+" "+uid);
    return true;
}

public boolean removeuser(String username, String uid) {
    out.println("remove invoked: "+username+" "+uid);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Show us the code where your try to "store the stream on the Red5 Server". Plesae describe what does and what doesn't work with it.

Comment: @Tichodroma, i have modified and explained whats happening, thanks for your reply

Comment: I have used streamlistener which outputs the packets but i need something simpler by using simpleplayitems

Comment: I found that creating a file aaa.flv in the streams folder gets rid of the error but the file aaa.flv does not contain any video from the stream

Comment: Also im going to use multiple streams coming through to the server application is it better to use multithreaded or just using applicationadapater

Comment: try using the `saveAs` method on `stream` variable itself